# Graphene: How to share models for calling methods for different resolver?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I am quite new to GraphQL and would like to create some data calculation API. I have defined some methods of some class which I would like utilize in my schema. Here is a minimum working example:

```
import graphene


class LocationData:
    def __init__(self, latitude, longitude, temperature):
        self.lat = latitude
        self.lng = longitude
        self.tmp = temperature

    def first_metric(self):
        return self.lat + self.lng

    def second_metric(self):
        return self.lat / self.tmp ** 2


class GeoInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    lat = graphene.Float(required=True)
    lng = graphene.Float(required=True)
    tmp = graphene.Float(required=True)


class FirstField(graphene.ObjectType):
    first_metric = graphene.Float()


class SecondField(graphene.ObjectType):
    second_metric = graphene.Float()
    third_metric = graphene.Float()


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    first = graphene.Field(FirstField, geo=GeoInput(required=True))
    second = graphene.Field(SecondField, geo=GeoInput(required=True))

    def resolve_first(self, info, geo):
        data = LocationData(geo.lat, geo.lng, geo.tmp)
        return FirstField(first_metric=data.first_metric())

    def resolve_second(self, info, geo):
        data = LocationData(geo.lat, geo.lng, geo.tmp)
        value1 = data.second_metric()
        value2 = value1+300
        return SecondField(second_metric=value1,
                           third_metric=value2)
```

The query currently looks like this:

```
query{
  first(geo: {lat: 30, lng: 20, tmp:2}){
    firstMetric
  }
  second(geo: {lat: 30, lng: 20, tmp:2}){
    secondMetric
    thirdMetric
  }
}
```

Here, I am wondering how I can share my LocationData object such that it is initialized only once and than its methods available for both resolve functions? I could not find any example in some docs. So, like or similiar to this:

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    first = graphene.Field(FirstField, geo=GeoInput(required=True))
    second = graphene.Field(SecondField, geo=GeoInput(required=True))
    data = LocationData(geo.lat, geo.lng, geo.tmp)

    def resolve_first(self, info, geo):
        return FirstField(first_metric=self.data.first_metric())

    def resolve_second(self, info, geo):
        value1 = self.data.second_metric()
        value2 = value1+300
        return SecondField(second_metric=value1,
                           third_metric=value2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to simply place all possible metrics in the same ObjectType and assign a resolver to it.

```py
class Metrics(graphene.ObjectType):
    first_metric = graphene.Float()
    second_metric = graphene.Float()
    third_metric = graphene.Float()

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    metrics = graphene.Field(Metrics, geo=GeoInput(required=True))

    def resolve_metrics(self, info, geo):
        data = LocationData(geo.lat, geo.lng, geo.tmp)
        return Metrics(first_metric=data.first_metric(),
                           second_metric=data.second_metric(),
                           third_metric=data.second_metric()+300)
```

A different way to do this to avoid unnecessary calculations may be to add an `__init__` method in the functions class and resolvers for each field. For instance:

```
class Metrics(graphene.ObjectType):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.geo_data = data

    first_metric = graphene.Float()
    second_metric = graphene.Float()
    third_metric = graphene.Float()

    def resolve_first_metric(self, info):
        print 'First'
        return self.geo_data.first_metric()

    def resolve_second_metric(self, info):
        print 'Second'
        return self.geo_data.second_metric()

    def resolve_third_metric(self, info):
        print 'Third'
        return self.geo_data.second_metric() + 300

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    metrics = graphene.Field(Metrics, geo=GeoInput(required=True))

    def resolve_metrics(self, info, geo):
        data = LocationData(geo.lat, geo.lng, geo.tmp)
        return Metrics(data)
```

If we execute this query with:

```
query {
  metrics (geo: {lat: 30, lng: 20, tmp:2}) {
    firstMetric
    thirdMetric
  }
}
```

We get

```
{
  "data": {
   "metrics": {
      "firstMetric": 50.0,
      "thirdMetric": 307.5
    }
  }
}
```

And from the console, we can see that `second_metric()` was not called.

```
First
Third
```